# Playwright base.url into allurereport

Tags: playwright, allure

How to add base.URL into allure playright report?

```
/*environmentInfo: 
    URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    ENV: process.env.test_env,
    OS_Platform: os.platform(),
    OS_Version: os.version(),
    Node_Version: process.version,
*/
```

this is undefined, I would like to add custom Base.URL into ALLURE playwright Environment section
I tried beforeEach or AfterEach like importing

```
//import { allure } from "allure-playwright";
however I can't see any public method like this one
//allure.addEnvironment('URL', URL or process.env.BASE_URL)
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried [environment-information](https://allurereport.org/docs/playwright/#environment-information), instead of adding information to your test cases ? By the provided information we cannot determine what you have tried, what the error message was etc. Please add more. The other env variables can be read ?